# Generating Sine Waves at Changing Frequency

Tags: algorithm, audio, signal-processing, trigonometry

I am using the following function to generate a sine wave for playback in my audio application:

```
public double NextSample(double frequency)
{
    Math.Sin(2.0 * Math.PI * frequency * position++ / sampleRate);
}
```

Where 'position' is simply the total number of samples that have been requested (and thus 'position' divided by 'sampleRate' represents the current time).

The function produces the expected result as long as the frequency passed to it remains constant. However, if I try to sweep between frequencies for example, the result is quite strange. I can't really describe it other than to say that while frequency is changing, the output of the function does not sound like the frequency that is passed to it.

Can anyone explain this?

EDIT: For future reference, here is the solution:

```
public double NextSample(double frequency)
{
    Math.Sin(phase += 2 * Math.PI * frequency / sampleRate);
}
```

Comment: Try plotting the results of your code rather than playing them, and you'll see the problem.

Comment: Actually, I was plotting them, and the problem was not clear. Because the frequency was changing by very small increments for each sample, there were no visible discontinuities. Therefore, the result was not audible distortion, but just a different frequency than the one passed to the function.